# Processing several files in SPARK separately

Tags: java, apache-spark

I need help with implementation one workflow with Apache Spark. My task is in next:

1. I have several CSV files as source data. Note: these files could has different layout
2. I have metadata with info how I need parse each file (this is not problem)
3. Main goal: result is source file with several additional columns. I have to update each source file without joining to one output range. For example: source 10 files -> 10 result files and each result file have data only from corresponding source file.

As I know Spark can open many files by mask:

```
 var source = sc.textFile("/source/data*.gz");
```

But in this case I can't recognize which line of a file. If I get list of source files and try to process by following scenario:

```
JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(...);
List<String> files = new ArrayList() //list of source files full name's
for(String f : files)
{
   JavaRDD<String> data = sc.textFile(f);
   //process this file with Spark
   outRdd.coalesce(1, true).saveAsTextFile(f + "_out"); 
}
```

But in this case I will processed all files in sequential mode.

My question is next: how I can processed many files in parallel mode?. For example: one file - one executor?

I tried to implement this by simple code with source data:

```
//JSON file with paths to 4 source files, saved in inData variable
{
"files": [
    {
        "name": "/mnt/files/DigilantDaily_1.gz",
        "layout": "layout_1"
    },
    {
        "name": "/mnt/files/DigilantDaily_2.gz",
        "layout": "layout_2"
    },
    {
        "name": "/mnt/files/DigilantDaily_3.gz",
        "layout": "layout_3"
    },
    {
        "name": "/mnt/files/DigilantDaily_4.gz",
        "layout": "layout_4"
    }
  ]
 }

sourceFiles= new ArrayList<>();
    JSONObject jsFiles = (JSONObject) new JSONParser().parse(new FileReader(new File(inData)));
    Iterator<JSONObject> iterator = ((JSONArray)jsFiles.get("files")).iterator();
    while (iterator.hasNext()){
        SourceFile sf = new SourceFile();
        JSONObject js = iterator.next();
        sf.FilePath = (String) js.get("name");
        sf.MetaPath = (String) js.get("layout");
        sourceFiles.add(sf);
    }

    SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf()
            .setMaster("local[*]")
            .setAppName("spark-app");
    final JavaSparkContext sparkContext = new JavaSparkContext(sparkConf);

    try {

        final Validator validator = new Validator();

        ExecutorService pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4);

        for(final SourceFile f : sourceFiles)
        {
            pool.execute(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {

                    final Path inFile = Paths.get(f.FilePath);

                    JavaRDD<String> d1 = sparkContext
                            .textFile(f.FilePath)
                            .filter(new Function<String, Boolean>() {
                                @Override
                                public Boolean call(String s) throws Exception {
                                    return validator.parseRow(s);
                                }
                            });

                    JavaPairRDD<String, Integer> d2 = d1.mapToPair(new PairFunction<String, String, Integer>() {
                        @Override
                        public Tuple2<String, Integer> call(String s) throws Exception {
                            String userAgent = validator.getUserAgent(s);
                            return new Tuple2<>(DeviceType.deviceType(userAgent), 1);
                        }
                    });

                    JavaPairRDD<String, Integer> d3 = d2.reduceByKey(new Function2<Integer, Integer, Integer>() {
                        @Override
                        public Integer call(Integer val1, Integer val2) throws Exception {
                            return val1 + val2;
                        }
                    });

                    d3.coalesce(1, true)
                            .saveAsTextFile(outFolder + "/" + inFile.getFileName().toString());//, org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.GzipCodec.class);
                }
            });
        }
        pool.shutdown();
        pool.awaitTermination(60, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw e;
    } finally {
        if (sparkContext != null) {
            sparkContext.stop();
        }
    }
```

But this code failed with exception:

```
Exception in thread "pool-13-thread-2" Exception in thread "pool-13-thread-3" Exception in thread "pool-13-thread-1" Exception in thread "pool-13-thread-4" java.lang.Error: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1151)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
  Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable
at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.ensureSerializable(ClosureCleaner.scala:304)
at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.org$apache$spark$util$ClosureCleaner$$clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:294)
at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:122)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.clean(SparkContext.scala:2032)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$filter$1.apply(RDD.scala:335)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$filter$1.apply(RDD.scala:334)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:147)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:108)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:310)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.filter(RDD.scala:334)
at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDD.filter(JavaRDD.scala:78)
at append.dev.App$1.run(App.java:87)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
... 2 more
```

I would like to know where I have a mistake?

Thanks for help me!

Answer (score 0):

You could use `sc.wholeTextFiles(dirname)` to get an RDD of `(filename, content)` pairs and map over that.

Comment: and then what? How would you load each file from disk? You can't do `fileRdd.flatMap(file => sc.textFile(file))` because you shouldn't try serializing the context.

Comment: `wholeTextFiles` is risky too - if one of the files is larger than 2GB, you'll get an exception (because it loads each file as a single record, and there's a 2GB limit on the size of a partition in Spark). And even if you don't get an exception - you'll get bad performance.

Comment: **How would you load each file from disk?** Yes, all files placed on HDFS

Comment: Yes. I would not load each files into memory by `wholeTextFiles` because several files can be > 2 GB

Comment: Altough splitting your files beforehand might make more sense, if the files are on hdfs, you have access to them on the executors too, right? Maybe you could 1. get list of filenames, convert it to an rdd with sc.parallelize, map over it, and open the files and parse them in the map phase on the executors line by line?

Answer (score 0):

I have used a similar multithreaded approach with good results. I beleive the problem is located in the inner class you define.

Create your runnable/callable on a separate class and make sure it gets across to Spark with you submitted jars. Also, implement serializable as you are implicitly passing state to your function (f.FilePath).

Comment: 2 **Ioannis Deligiannis**     Hi! Do you think that I should move my anonymous Runnable class from main method to separate class in external jar? Could you provide me short example where this works ??

Comment: Yes. This will also make clear tha you essentially pass "state" to you function. Inner classes and lambdas are a little more tricky to use with spark. Try this first and the serialization exception should go away. Depending on how you sent your code to Spark, you might not need an extra jar.

Comment: Sorry, you should actually move the anonymous Function<> first. Is the validator serializable?

Comment: Is the validator serializable? - My answer Yes.

Comment: Is the containing class serializable?

Comment: if I delete all content of run(){...} method and still only `long n = sparkContext.textFile(f.FilePath).count()` all work OK. I think that JavaRDD<T> is not serializable

Comment: Rdd is not serializable.  However i coundnt see it being passed in a function (though i m using a mobile). I've seen the same when you create an inner class from a class that is not serializable. Take the function out of this containing class, implement serializable and it should work.

Comment: Hi  Ioannis Deligiannis, After moving my task code from anonymous to separate file all works OK! Thanks you for help!